# Meaning of ~タガとして

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of タガとして in this sentence?

> 革新勢力が、保守陣営を大きく制約する**タガとして**機能する...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「革新勢力{かくしんせいりょく}が、保守陣営{ほしゅじんえい}を大{おお}きく制約{せいやく}するタガとして機能{きのう}する...」

「タガ」 originally means "hoops".  There is a kanji for it ,「箍{たが}」, but that is not taught in Japanese schools, so feel free to write it in kana.

[image]
<sub>(source: [yimg.jp](https://iwiz-chie.c.yimg.jp/im_siggbPS3lnFCOmieZqQBB9Y68Q---x320-y320-exp5m-n1/d/iwiz-chie/ans-415618450))</sub>

「たが/タガ」 are what keep all the wood pieces of a barrel together.  Without them, you only have separate pieces of wood that will not function as a tool.

In the sentence in question, 「タガ」 is used figuratively to mean "***controlling power over another***".

> "The progressive forces function as the controlling power in greatly restricting the conservative camp."

「タガとして」 = "as the hoops" → "as the (inconspicuous) controlling power"